# SQL stored procedure not returning string value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following code of the stored procedure. I just want to return the message if already present in DB it should return message it is repeated otherwise inset data and show a message done

**SQL stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_AddProjectManager]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @ProjectId int,
        @EmployeeId int,
        @uid nvarchar(128)
        
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @Organization_Id int = (select Organization_Id from Employees where User_Account_Id = @uid);
        declare @Office_Id int = (select Office_Id from Employees where User_Account_Id = @uid);
        declare @output nvarchar(50);
        declare @dup int =(select count(*) from Project_Managers where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId and ProjectId=@ProjectId);
        
        
    
        if(@dup=0)
            begin
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Project_Managers]
                       ([EmployeeId]
                       ,[ProjectId]
                       ,[User_Account_Id]
                       ,[Office_Id]
                       ,[Organization_Id]
                       ,[CreatedOn]
                       ,[UpdatedOn]
                       ,[CreatedBy]
                       ,[UpdatedBy]
                       ,[Is_active]
                       )
                 VALUES(@EmployeeId,@ProjectId,@uid,@Office_Id,@Organization_Id,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),@uid,@uid,1);
                 SET @output= 'Done';
             end
         else
             begin
                SET @output ='Repeated';
             end
         return convert(varchar(10),@output)
    END
```

can't return the string value it shows following err:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_AddProjectManager, Line 43 [Batch Start Line 2]
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Repeated' to data type int.
```

**C# Code**

```
 public static string Add_ProjectManager(ProjectManagers PM)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd_insertion = new SqlCommand())
            {
                conn c = new conn();
                SqlConnection _Con = c.conect();
                cmd_insertion.Connection = _Con;
                _Con.Open();
                cmd_insertion.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd_insertion.CommandText = "SP_AddProjectManager";
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", PM.ProjectId);
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", PM.EmployeeId);
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", PM.userId);

                SqlParameter retval = cmd_insertion.Parameters.Add("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                cmd_insertion.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string status = (string)cmd_insertion.Parameters["@output"].Value;
                _Con.Close();
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.Clear();
                return status;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You declared `@output` as `int` while your probably meant `nvarchar(...)`. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: It's a stored procedure, it can only RETURN an int...you can SELECT your result or pass in an OUTPUT parameter and set it.

Comment: even after using nvarchar it shows same error

Comment: Dear all,
I have updated the code it also have same error

Comment: If you want you can use print(output) and see in messages tab

Comment: @SimonWilson so we can't return a string in anycase?

Comment: Not as a RETURN value no. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'll give you an example as an answer...

Comment: yes please @SimonWilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15) param, like this...(disclaimer, not in front of a sql editor)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_AddProjectManager]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @ProjectId int,
        @EmployeeId int,
        @uid nvarchar(128),
        @output nvarchar(50) OUTPUT
        
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @Organization_Id int = (select Organization_Id from Employees where User_Account_Id = @uid);
        declare @Office_Id int = (select Office_Id from Employees where User_Account_Id = @uid);
        declare @output nvarchar(50);
        declare @dup int =(select count(*) from Project_Managers where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId and ProjectId=@ProjectId);
        
        
    
        if(@dup=0)
            begin
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Project_Managers]
                       ([EmployeeId]
                       ,[ProjectId]
                       ,[User_Account_Id]
                       ,[Office_Id]
                       ,[Organization_Id]
                       ,[CreatedOn]
                       ,[UpdatedOn]
                       ,[CreatedBy]
                       ,[UpdatedBy]
                       ,[Is_active]
                       )
                 VALUES(@EmployeeId,@ProjectId,@uid,@Office_Id,@Organization_Id,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),@uid,@uid,1);
                 SET @output= 'Done';
             end
         else
             begin
                SET @output ='Repeated';
             end
       
    END
```

And you would call it something like this...

```
DECLARE @output varchar(50);
EXEC [dbo].[SP_AddProjectManager] 6, 66, '81873272', @output OUTPUT
SELECT @output 
-- OR
PRINT @Output
```

Or, if you don't want output params, replace your "RETURN" statement with a "SELECT"

Your C# code, again, no editor used, so off top of my head...

```
public static string Add_ProjectManager(ProjectManagers PM)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd_insertion = new SqlCommand())
    {
        using (conn c = new conn()) // Whatever this is
        {
            using (SqlConnection _Con = c.conect())
            {
                cmd_insertion.Connection = _Con;
                cmd_insertion.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd_insertion.CommandText = "SP_AddProjectManager";
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", PM.ProjectId); // .AddWithValue() is bad
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", PM.EmployeeId);
                cmd_insertion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", PM.userId);

                SqlParameter retval = cmd_insertion.Parameters.Add("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                _Con.Open();

                cmd_insertion.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string status = retval.Value;
                _Con.Close();
                return status;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should I add in same stored procedure I am sorry I didn't understand please elaborate

Comment: The first code example is your sproc, with an output parameter. The second example is how you would call it from within SQL. How are you using the sproc? What's the result being used for?

Comment: I want to call in asp.net code 

SqlParameter retval = cmd_insertion.Parameters.Add("@output",SqlDbType.VarChar);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

Comment: Ah...you did not mention C# in your post. So, replace your `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` to be `ParameterDirection.Output`...exec the sproc in code, then you can access `retval.Value`
Or, post your C# code in your question and I will correct it

Comment: sir so nice of you Thank you so much let me post it in my question Please

Comment: Please check edited Question

Comment: Please check edited answer @amaddurrani